# Flutter - is it possible to run flutter macOS app built with m1 chip on intel chip?

Tags: flutter, apple-m1

If possible, is there any specific setting needed? Or it'll just run without anything? I do not own intel based macOS machines, so hard to check... Great if anybody can share your experiences in publishing macOS apps.

Answer (score 1):

It should run in both environments with no problems:

> As of Flutter 3, Flutter macOS desktop apps are built as universal binaries, with native support for both existing Intel-based Macs and Apple's latest Apple Silicon devices.

Comment: Hi Dave, welcome to Stack Overflow. When you cite a piece of documentation or anything else, you should also include the source so that other users can verify your answer or read more about the topic. [What's new in Flutter 3](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-8c74a5bc32d0)

Comment: I understand that the *release* version (what you upload to the store) is a universal binary, but a debug version is only for the current platform.